# Tensorflow lite model not outputting multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I've converted a model to Tensorflow Lite but the output shapes of the original model and tensorflow lite model aren't the same

Original Model:

```
model.outputs
```

The output is

```
[<tf.Tensor 'bidirectional/concat:0' shape=(None, 18, 800) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'concatenate/concat:0' shape=(None, 800) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'concatenate_1/concat:0' shape=(None, 800) dtype=float32>]
```

For tensorflow lite model:

```
interpreter.get_output_details()
```

The outputs are

```
[{'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'index': 51,
  'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:2',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
   'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32)},
  'shape': array([  1, 800], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([ -1, 800], dtype=int32),
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
 {'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'index': 50,
  'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:1',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
   'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32)},
  'shape': array([  1, 800], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([ -1, 800], dtype=int32),
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
 {'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'index': 49,
  'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:0',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
   'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32)},
  'shape': array([1, 1, 1], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([-1, -1, -1], dtype=int32),
  'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

The two (1, 800) shape outputs (index 51 and 50) are correct but the last output shape is of (1,1,1) instead of (1,18, 800).

This is happening with another model too, where the output is a multidimensional array of shape (1, 40, 7000) but the Tensorflow lite model is outputting (1, 1, 7000) shape